# Diagnosing frozen screen in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I am a new user. I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 as a dual boot on a fairly standard Dell Dimension, 768 RAM, Intel 2 GHz chip. The first few times I ran it it was a bit slow, with a lot of flickering of the mouse cursor, but then it seemed to settle down. Today, the screen has frozen. I was running Firefox, gedit, and Terminal. Neither the mouse nor the keyboard seem to work, although I am not familiar with the control sequences I might use in Ubuntu, such as Ctrl Alt Del (is there something like task manager on Windows?). 
Could anyone please advise me on such control sequences, and if they fail, how I can find out what is causing the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Many users are disappointed of Ubuntu 11 with Unity desktop. It's still buggy and slow. If you feel everything is slow, downgrade to Ubuntu 10 which is the most usable version. I believe things will work fine in Ubuntu 12 which will be released in April. You can tryout Luninux 11.10, which uses Gnome 3 instead of Unity. Luninux is a MacOS like and developped from Ubuntu, but a better working OS(See below). Download --> http://luninuxos.com/?page_id=18
[image: Luninux]

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a good idea. Why try to thrash something into shape that may not be that good to begin with. I'll give one of these a try. I have no reason to doubt my hardware as the Windows XP works fine.